# I was in the middle of an upgrade when I accidentaly pressed ctrl+c. I can no longer open a terminal and I cannot shut down with a GUI

Tags: command-line, 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, shutdown

As the title says I borked an upgrade. It paused for a moment to ask me something about gnome settings, and I pressed "D" for details, and then ctrl+c to try and get out of the output it gave.

Now I cannot open a terminal, nor can I shutdown through the GUI. Firefox is working fin though obviously. Alt+F2 also works, or at least the command window pops up

*What Should I do to keep my system working, and to start up the upgrade again?

**In my haste I forgot that I have a recent back to restore to and do the upgrade again after restore. I will try that route and update here for posterity.

**Final Update**

Thanks for the help everyone. I've decided to call in the firing squad.

I formatted the drive with my laptop, and then attempted a fresh install of 18.04 so that I could recover my settings and documents with the Deja Dup backup I made before starting the upgrade.

This introduced another error where I'm stuck in TTY after boot. There will be yet another post about that. Please follow me on this cortisol-fueled adventure of the failed upgrade.

Cheers.

Comment: Reinstall from scratch with the new version is what I would be doing at this point.

Comment: Log in in the console (CTRL-Alt-F2) There might be messages on login directing you on what to do. Follow them. IF no directions are given try running `sudo do-release-upgrade` again.

Comment: You weren't clear on where the upgrade was up to.. I gather it was installing packages given your description, but I'd likely still view the sources (I'd assume they'll point to *focal* given your tags imply to me you're in a *release-upgrade* from 18.04 to 20.04).  Assuming sources look good, I'd `sudo apt full-upgrade` to see if it continues.. I'd hope for clues from the messages; but you may have issues as the other process was killed; it may be locking the upgrade from occurring.. but I'd base what I'd do on details I can see & had seen (ie. where in the upgrade cycle it was likely up to)

Comment: I've calmed down a bit now, and I realize that I am actually using 20.04 now, although I do not have permission to shutdown, nor open the file explorer or terminals. I cannot input commands and am afraid to restart.

I believe it was up to installing the new Gnome settings(?), since that is what caused this whole issue.

Comment: My prior comment was assuming you can login via a text terminal as @SorenA suggested.   You can always safely shutdown using SysRq commands to direct to the kernel (use that rather than using power-off of pulling cable; ie. a REISUB to reboot is much safer. But try what was suggested from terminal